# Laws of Equivalence with 4 terms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Use equivalence laws to show that $(A ∨ C) ∧ (B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ D) ∧ (B ∨ D)$
and $(A ∧ B) ∨ (C ∧ D)$ are logically equivalent.

I am trying to figure out how to go about this problem. The part that confuses me is that there are 4 separate terms. How would you apply the laws on that?

Comment: Hint: Apply Distribution three times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $(A ∨ C) ∧ (B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ D) ∧ (B ∨ D)$,

we see that using the distributive law on the first two clauses, and on the second two clauses, we simplify the left hand side to:

$$((A \land B) \lor C) \land ((A\land B) \lor D)\tag{1}$$

Using the distributive law again, now on $(1)$, we find that  $$((A \land B) \lor C) \land ((A\land B) \lor D)\equiv (A\land B) \lor (C\land D)$$ as desired.

Comment: Indeed you can: the distributive laws can be used in each direction, because they declare that each side of, say $(P\land Q) \lor R \equiv (P\lor R) \land (Q\lor R)$  In any sort of equivalence each side is equivalent to the other, just like $a=b$ is not different that $b=a$.

Comment: So would that hold true for other laws as well? For example, can I write P as P ^P?

Comment: Sure you can.  And, also, for example DeMorgan's:  $\lnot(a \lor b) \equiv \lnot a \land \lnot b$, and $\lnot(a \land b) \equiv \lnot a \lor \lnot b$.  You can replace either side of those equivalences with the other side.